# Swift - Hide & Show Object

Tags: ios, swift

When I press the button hide to my text, after I press button to show my text. Where is my fault? My English very bad, sorry...

```
@IBOutlet weak var myHiddenText: UILabel!

@IBAction func showBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
  myHiddenText.hidden = true

  if myHiddenText.hidden == true {
    myHiddenText.hidden = false
  }

  if myHiddenText.hidden == false {
    myHiddenText.hidden = true
  }

}
```

Comment: `myHiddenText` is a string. Strings can't be hidden, only views.

Comment: @TroyT Huh? `myHiddenText` is declared as a `UILabel`.

Comment: @rmaddy he just changed it to be a `UILabel`. The original edit had `myHiddenText` be a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the button to toggle the `hidden` property of the label, simply do this:

```
@IBAction func showBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    myHiddenText.hidden = !myHiddenText.hidden
}
```

Your main issue was this line:

```
myHiddenText.hidden = true
```

This was hiding the label every time then your `if` statement would always be true and show your label. Then the second `if` statement would be true and hide the label again.

So another option to fix your code would be:

```
@IBAction func showBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    if myHiddenText.hidden == true {
        myHiddenText.hidden = false
    } else {
        myHiddenText.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly how to replace 5 lines of replicated code into 1 :) Only one suggestion: the name of the method should be something like `toggleLabelVisibility`.

Comment: Thank you! It works. I've been working for two hours.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not help you but it may help someone else. If you want to hide multiple objects you could do this.

Step 1: Reference all the objects you want to hide with @IBOutlet

Step 2: Declare this variable

```
var buttons_are_hidden: Bool = false
```

Step 3: Put this code where you need it

```
if self.buttons_are_hidden == true {
        self.first_object.isHidden = true
        self.second_object.isHidden = true
        self.third_object.isHidden = true
        self.buttons_are_hidden = true
    } else {
            self.first_object.isHidden = true
            self.second_object.isHidden = true
            self.third_object.isHidden = true
            self.buttons_are_hidden = true
        }
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

With [UIKitPlus library](https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/UIKitPlus) you can do it simply like this

```swift
class MyViewController: ViewController {
    @State var hiddency = false

    override func buildUI() {
        super.buildUI()
        body {
            VStack {
                View().height(10).background(.red).hidden($hiddency)
                View().height(10).background(.green).hidden($hiddency)
                View().height(10).background(.blue).hidden($hiddency)
                Button("toggle").onTapGesture {
                    self.hiddency.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at it, it works since iOS9+ and have LivePreview.